# SQL query - Beginner

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL. I need SQL query to achieve the mentioned output.
I have asked a similar query but that doesn't describe my problem well. Here is my detailed requirement.

I have a table with data as below

```
Table: boxes
+------------+----------+
| box_id     | Status   | 
+------------+----------+
| 1          | created  |
| 2          | created  |
| 3          | opened   |
| 4          | opened   |
| 5          | closed   |
| 6          | closed   |
| 7          | closed   |
| 8          | wrapped  |
+------------+----------+
```

With this there is also a status names `destroyed` But for which there is no box destroyed.

I need an output like this

```
+--------------+-------+
| Status       | Count |
+--------------+-------+
| created      | 2     |
| opened       | 2     |
| destroyed    | 0     |
| other_status | 4     |    # this includes status (closed and wrapped)
| total        | 8     |
+--------------+-------+
```

How can this be achieved in SQL. Thanks in advance

Comment: What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MSSQL or MySQL8.0, you can use CTE as below to achieve your required output-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5af857b5c71efa3fc65f3b2cb0230039)

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 'created' Status UNION ALL
    SELECT 'opened'  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'destroyed'  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'other_status' 
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN Status IN ('created','opened','destroyed') THEN Status 
        ELSE 'other_status' 
    END Status,
    SUM(1) Cnt
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY
    CASE 
        WHEN Status IN ('created','opened','destroyed') THEN Status 
        ELSE 'other_status' 
    END
)


SELECT CTE.Status,ISNULL(CTE2.Cnt, 0) Cnt
FROM CTE LEFT JOIN CTE2 ON CTE.Status = CTE2.Status

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Total' Status, SUM(CTE2.Cnt) FROM CTE2
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion But I want to achieve this in SQL

Comment: SQL is not the database for sure :) which database you are using?

Comment: BTW, you can use the given logic for any database @Subi

Comment: mysql it is. Either MySql or Amazon Redshift - I use both

Comment: MySQL version ?

Comment: Initially, I didn't understand this. After working for few hours I got the flow. This is what I was expecting. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following code.

```
select status, count(box_id) 
  from table 
 where status in ('created','opened', 'destroyed')  
 group by status

UNION ALL

select 'other_status' status, count(box_id) 
  from table 
 where status not in ('created','opened', 'destroyed')  

UNION ALL

select 'total' status, count(box_id) 
  from table;
```

Comment: Is this efficient query? In my DB the Table contains 100 million rows.  This way I need to run same query thrice

Comment: You can just try it. Its the best way to find out if it is efficient. In my opinion it should be efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it is less efficient with the volume of data I am managing